# Improving efficiency in automobileIC Engines

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I think that the varying load in roads affect the efficiency of IC engines in large amounts. I am planning to do a mechanism which stores the power produced in IC engines mechanically, and then release it as per requirement to the drive. Would such a system be feasible. Can anyone suggest an idea for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, research flywheel energy storage - and it has been used, IIRC on busses / coaches in the past, but some systems had issues with catastrophic failure.